# Dates in For Loop in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, foreach

In vb.net I have two data values as shown below:

```
Dim startp as datetime
Dim endp as datetime
```

I have a function called `ProcessData(soemdate)` which processes dataporting.

In VB.net is there a way I can do something like

```
For each day between startp and endp
 ProcessData(soemdate)
Next
```

Thanks

Comment: Just my 2 cents here, but if your function is really called "ProcessData" you might want to consider something a tad more descriptive for maintainability. If that was just a hypothetical function name, please ignore this comment.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is another way to do this.

```
Dim startP As DateTime = New DateTime(2009, 1, 1)
Dim endP As DateTime = New DateTime(2009, 2, 1)
Dim CurrD As DateTime = startP

While (CurrD <= endP)        
    ProcessData(CurrD)
    Console.WriteLine(CurrD.ToShortDateString)
    CurrD = CurrD.AddDays(1)
End While
```

Answer (score 20):

```
For Each Day As DateTime in Enumerable.Range(0, (endp - startp).Days) _
                            .Select(Function(i) startp.AddDays(i)) 
    ProcessData(Day)
Next Day
```

Comment: +1 for the enumerable.range approach (cool trick)
-1 for being a bit obfuscated as to the purpose for whomever needs to support it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay on VB translation- something came up at work that took priority on my attention.

Comment: I admit the Enumerable.Range trick looks odd the first time you see, but it's one of those things that, once you get it, you wonder why you ever did it any other way.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to Joel Coehoorn's answer which I personally think should be the accepted answer as I always try to avoid While loops no matter how safe they may appear.  For...Each is a much safer approach although the enumerable isn't very pretty in-line.  You can however move it to a function to keep things more readable, plus you can re-use as needed.

```
For Each Day As DateTime In DateRange(StartDate, EndDate)
    ProcessData(Day)
    Console.WriteLine(Day.ToShortDateString)
Next

Public Shared Function DateRange(Start As DateTime, Thru As DateTime) As IEnumerable(Of Date)
    Return Enumerable.Range(0, (Thru.Date - Start.Date).Days + 1).Select(Function(i) Start.AddDays(i))
End Function
```

I also added 1 to Enumerable range since as Joel had it, it wouldn't return the end date and in my situation I needed it to return all dates in the range including the start and end days.

Enumerable.Range is a sort of loop in itself that adds i days to the startdate advancing i with each call from in this case 0 to the difference between start and end days + 1.  So the first time it's called you get the result of Start.AddDays(0), next you'll get Start.AddDays(1) and so on until the range is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily loop through each day if you convert your dates to *[OLE Automation Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx)* `OADate` where the left portion represents the day and the right portion represents the time.

For example `#06/19/2018#.ToOADate` converts to `43270.0`

```
For loopDate As Double = #06/19/2018#.ToOADate To #07/01/2018#.ToOADate

    Dim thisDate As Date = DateTime.FromOADate(loopDate)

    ' Do your stuff here e.g. ProcessData(thisDate)

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an accumulator date:

```
Dim Accumulator as DateTime
Accumulator = startp

While (Accumulator <= endp)


    Accumulator = Accumulator.AddDays(1)
End While
```

Not tested, and I'm a C# programmer, so be easy if my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For those that come looking later, I had to add a +1 to the Range endpoint to get this to work for when the start and end were the same.  Here is the code I used.

```
For Each Day As DateTime in Enumerable.Range(0, (endp - startp).Days + 1)                            .Select(Function(i) startp.AddDays(i)) 
    'Do work here
Next Day
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a calendar table with all dates and query values from there.

SQL:

```
Select Date as MyDate from tblCalendar Where Date >= StartDt And Date <= EndDate
```

.NET:

```
While Reader.read
  process(MyDate)
End While
```